# Real-Time notification using laravel as back-end API and AngularJS as front-end

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, notifications

Is it possible to use Real-time notification in AngularJS when the back-end api is laravel? should I user laravel echo in AngularJS or there is another solution for it?

As I've searched I should use pusher as websocket server, and should use laravel echo which is a JS library.

The question is should I use laravel-echo library in AngularJS or there is another solution for it?

FYI: laravel (back-end) api is separated from AngularJS (front-end) they communicate through CRUD requests which is authenticated using O-Auth.

Comment: You could use socket.IO, It is possible to integrate with laravel, check this post, https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d

Comment: @Luillyfe good point, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue using laravel + redis + socket.io + socket client, I put my solution here hope to stop wasting others time trying to figure it out.

```
cd your-project-name
```

Install packages

```
npm install express ioredis socket.io --save
```

Your package.json file will look like

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "ioredis": "^1.4.0",
    "redis": "^0.12.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5"
  }
}

composer require predis/predis
```

Creating the Event

```
php artisan make:event EventName
```

Make sure that it `implements ShouldBroadcast`

The entire EventName.php class should look like:

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EventName extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
        );
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

use this code in angular js :

```
<script src="js/socket.io.js'"></script>
    <script>
        //var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
        socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
        });
    </script>
```

Routing
Set up three routes like so. Add them to your `app/Http/routes.php` file.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // this doesn't do anything other than to
    // tell you to go to /fire
    return "go to /fire";
});

Route::get('fire', function () {
    // this fires the event
    event(new App\Events\EventName());
    return "event fired";
});

Route::get('test', function () {
    // this checks for the event
    return view('test');
});
```

Create the `socket.js` file in your project root

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

FYI : Make sure you have installed `redis` server + connect it to `Laravel` using `.env` or database file.

Comment: where should i `socket.js` included?

Comment: In your project root directory.

Comment: I am getting error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.10.10:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFjDQl0. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: Now working fine.. thank you very much.. @Mohammad_Hosseini saved me a lot hours.. thanks

Comment: @shihabudheen Anytime, please vote up If it was helpful.

Comment: @mohammed_hossin when a notification broadcasting to a specfic user, how can I receive message, `socket.on("App.User.41", function (message) {                  alert(2)                });`  not working

Answer (score 0):

I used @Mohammad_Hosseini's solution before but after upgrading Laravel 5.4 to 5.8 it's not working anymore.
Last but not least; @Mohammad_Hosseini's solution not included auth and private channels.

So, I highly suggest use laravel-echo-server for easy upgrade. Also, it's open-source and maintenance by the great community.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete it or change it into one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: thanks for mentioning it's not working in laravel 5.8, I'll be looking into that as soon as I find free time. but this is not an answer and should be written as a comment.

Comment: notice that this is a solution for running a socket server of your own project and not using any third party.